# Run WDS Image programmatically

Tags: c++, wds

Is there a way to launch WDS image from c++ app?

I basically need an app to install correct Windows after user's Order Number input.
At the moment it's manual process and human make mistakes, to avoid it I want an c++ app to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WDS takes control when "booting" a PC. On client's boot, depending on the architecture, a particular Boot.wim Windows PE image is loaded and run. That image is able to retrieve all the available install options (menu) from the WDS repository.
You can automate/control certain parameters of the process but there's not a public API or BINL protocol interface allowing you to interact from a third party application.